# Problem with GeoServer when I try to add data storage "Error message: Timer already cancelled"

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have a problem with GeoServer when I try to add data storage give me this: "

> Error message: Timer already cancelled

Does someone have any idea of this problem and a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file. We also need to know the version of GeoServer, your operating system, what sort of data you are adding, where it is stored etc